# Run-time error 1004: Method OnKey of object _Application failed

Tags: excel, vba

I'm getting reports of VBA **"Run-time error '1004': Method 'OnKey' of object '_Application' failed"** at least on Excel 2016 under Windows in this code:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Deactivate()
    Application.OnKey "^x"
End Sub
```

(The code overrides certain hotkeys when my VBA-enabled workbook is active, and restores the default behavior when the user switches back to another workbook.)

What could be the reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unexpectedly, many API calls fail when the active workbook is in the **[Protected view](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/what-is-protected-view-d6f09ac7-e6b9-4495-8e43-2bbcdbcb6653)** mode. I wasn't even able to switch the active workbook to `ThisWorkbook` via `Activate`.

The workaround I came up with is to dismiss "Protected view" when the user switches to such a document from my app/workbook:

```
If Not (Application.ActiveProtectedViewWindow Is Nothing) Then
    Application.ActiveProtectedViewWindow.Edit
End If
Application.OnKey "^x"
```

This gives up some of its protection, but as my users are working mainly with internal documents, this tradeoff makes sense.