# Runtime error 1004 Method OnKey of object '_Application' failed

Tags: excel, vba

the following code causes

runtime error '1004'
Method OnKey of object '_Application' failed!
Any suggestions?

```
Sub MyAchieve()
  Dim col As Integer
  Dim row As Integer
  col = activeCell.column
  row = activeCell.row
  col = col + 1
  'Range(Cells(row, col), Cells(row, col)).Select
  Cells(row, col).Select
End Sub
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
  Dim activeCell As Range
  Set activeCell = Selection
  If activeCell.column >= 1 And activeCell.column <= 10 Then
    Call Application.OnKey("ENTER", "MyAchieve")
  End If
End Sub
```

I hoped this link ( [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62880064/run-time-error-1004-method-onkey-of-object-application-failed][1]
)was helpful, but it is the Application.OnKey("ENTER", "..."), which fails.

---

The following is the improved code, which uses a valid key (RETURN instead of ENTER)

```
Option Explicit
Sub getDateTime()
  Dim EditDate As Date
  Dim rng As Range
  Set rng = Selection
  rng.Value = Format(Now(), "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm")
  getNextCell
  Exit Sub
error_handler:
  MsgBox "getDateTime() " & Err.Number
  Resume Next
End Sub
Sub getNextCell()
  activeCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate
End Sub
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
  Dim activeCell As Range
  Set activeCell = Selection
  Application.OnKey "{RETURN}", Cells(activeCell.row, activeCell.column + 1).Select
End Sub
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
  Application.OnKey "{RETURN}", Cells(activeCell.row, activeCell.column + 1).Select
End Sub
Private Sub Worksheet_Deactivate()
  Application.OnKey "{RETURN}"
End Sub
```

Comment: You didn't apply the solution you linked to?

Comment: There was no protective view!

Comment: I've never tried it, but it looks like `ENTER` is not a valid key. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.onkey - Maybe you wanted `{ENTER}` or `~`?

Comment: It is true: ENTER is not a valid key, RETURN is. Thank you. This resolved the problem described. However, with the improved code, which I copied into my question I was not able to achieve that using the enter key, the focus would be set to the right next cell, rather than below. I get the message: "Cannot run the macro 'name of my macro'. The macro may not be available in the workbook or all macros may be disabled.

Comment: Would anybody care to reply to this, please?

Answer (score 0):

This was the correct answer. The link showed that it was {RETURN} I needed to code. Thank you braX:

I've never tried it, but it looks like ENTER is not a valid key. learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.onkey - Maybe you wanted {ENTER} or ~? –
braX

This is the corrected code. The error I now get is something like this: "Cannot run the macro 'name of my macro'. The macro may not be available in the workbook or all macros may be disabled." So thank you. I got all the help I asked for.

```
Option Explicit
Sub getDateTime()
  Dim EditDate As Date
  Dim rng As Range
  Set rng = Selection
  rng.Value = Format(Now(), "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm")
  getNextCell
  Exit Sub
error_handler:
  MsgBox "getDateTime() " & Err.Number
  Resume Next
End Sub
Sub getNextCell()
  activeCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate
End Sub
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
  Dim activeCell As Range
  Set activeCell = Selection
  Application.OnKey "{RETURN}", Cells(activeCell.row, activeCell.column + 1).Select
End Sub
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
  Application.OnKey "{RETURN}", Cells(activeCell.row, activeCell.column + 1).Select
End Sub
Private Sub Worksheet_Deactivate()
  Application.OnKey "{RETURN}"
End Sub
```